# Mysql subquery fails, need help :)

Tags: php, sql, mysql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table `PICTURES`:

```
username varchar(50) 
picture_id varchar(50) 
datetime
```

...and I have a table `FRIENDS`:

```
user_1 varchar(50) 
user_2 varchar(50)  
datetime
```

When you have friends on the website your username goes in `user_1`,  and your friend username's go in `user_2`.  For each new friend a new row...

I want to show the 5 last pictures of the friends of one user (user_1)

so I try

```
SELECT p.picture_id, p.datetime
FROM pictures AS p
WHERE p.username = (
    SELECT f.user_2
    FROM friends AS f
    WHERE f.user_1 = '(ENTER USERNAME HERE)'
    ORDER BY f.datetime DESC
    LIMIT 5
)
ORDER BY p.datetime DESC;
```

And as you can see, the subquery return more than one row so... I need your help or suggestions to help me managing this solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `IN` instead of `=` in `WHERE p.username = (`.  Since you're selecting up to 5 rows `=` doesn't quite make sense.

```
SELECT p.picture_id, p.datetime
FROM pictures AS p
WHERE p.username IN (
    SELECT f.user_2
    FROM friends AS f
    WHERE f.user_1 = '(ENTER USERNAME HERE)'
    ORDER BY f.datetime DESC
    LIMIT 5
)
ORDER BY p.datetime DESC;
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help! It was pretty quick! BTW

I have to admit that '=' make no sense at all!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try a `JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT
    p.picture_id, p.datetime
FROM 
    friends AS f 
    INNER JOIN pictures AS p ON f.user_2 = p.username
WHERE
    f.user_1 = '(ENTER USERNAME HERE)'
ORDER BY
    p.datetime DESC
LIMIT 5
```

This will give you the last 5 pictures from any of `user_1`'s friends

Comment: This is a better approach, but may return multiple pictures from the same friend (if they've uploaded a load of new ones that are all newer than other friends'), which may or may not be the desired outcome.

Comment: @bobince - Hmm.. I figured that this was what OP wanted, from his description at least - his actual posted query would get 5 most recently added friends, and all their corresponding pictures

Comment: Yes, it's not entirely clear what the aim is. If it's a newest-per-friend query that's a groupwise maximum query, which is not as easy as it sounds. Bill's answer is the simplest approach (although potentially not the fastest; and all solutions to this kind of problem can return an unexpected number of rows when two pictures have the same timestamp).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean you want the latest 5 pictures from *each* of the friends, not the latest 5 pictures among all the friends' pictures.

This is one of the `greatest-n-per-group` problems that appears so frequently on StackOverflow.  Normally the problem is to find the top *one* from each group, but here's how I solve it when you want the top 5 or some other quantity:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM friends AS f
JOIN pictures AS p1 ON (f.user_2 = p1.username)
LEFT OUTER JOIN pictures AS p2 ON (p1.username = p2.username
    AND p1.datetime < p2.datetime)
WHERE f.user_1 = ?
GROUP BY p1.picture_id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 5;
```

Explanation: for each picture `p1` that belongs to one of my friends, count the pictures belonging to the same friend and with a more recent datetime.  The pictures that are in the most 5 recent must have fewer than 5 *other* pictures that are *more* recent.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `WHERE p.username =(subquery)` to `WHERE p.username in(subquery)`

SELECT p.picture_id, p.datetime FROM pictures AS p WHERE p.username **IN** (SELECT f.user_2 FROM friends AS f WHERE f.user_1 = '(ENTER USERNAME HERE)' ORDER BY f.datetime DESC LIMIT 5) ORDER BY p.datetime DESC;